# Changing from views to sql joins in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, join, hibernate-mapping

I have a domain object

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "vw_t_bucket")
public class TBucket {

....

@ManyToOne (cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Prd.class)
      @JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "key", referencedColumnName="key"),
          @JoinColumn(name = "cdate", referencedColumnName="cdate")
      })
      public IPrd getPrd() {
        return prd;
      }
....

      @ManyToOne (cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Acct.class)
      @JoinColumn (name = "acct", nullable = false)
      public IAcct getAcct() {
            return acct;
      }

}

@Entity
@Table (name = "product")
public class Prd implements IPrd {
...
}


@Entity
@Table (name = "vw_acct")
public class Acct implements IAcct {
...
}
```

As you can see, TBucket is a view, and is joined to table ( product ) and another view ( vw_acct)

I have been told by my db that a join with both views and tables will perform poorly and I need to change the views to tables.

But, the views themselves are made up of joins from multiple tables.

My Lead was wondering if there is a solution where we can put the join sql directly in the annotation and I told him that we can use tables/views only for mapping with domain objects.

I am wondering if there are any possible solutions to this problem.

Comment: There is no reason why a join between views and tables would necessarily perform poorly.  Maybe these particular joins would perform poorly (I will assume that is what your DBA meant), but it has nothing to do with the fact that you are joining views and tables.

Comment: I agree with Todd and would suggest investigating and understanding the specific performance issues with the current queries. In Oracle you would need to read up on using EXPLAIN PLAN to understand and apply that to the queries in question.

Comment: Quoting DBA - "We also have view joined with other tables/views. We should only have table to table joins or a simple select from view."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not update this entity, you can use the org.hibernate.annotations.Subselect annotation to name exact SQL to use.  It was actually developed (well on the HBM XML mapping side) a long time ago as a stand-in for views on databases that did not support views.  But, like I mentioned, it is read-only.

If you need to update, then you would need to use the org.hibernate.annotations.Loader, org.hibernate.annotations.SQLInsert, org.hibernate.annotations.SQLUpdate and  org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete annotations to fully map the enity.

Yet, another option (depending on exact nature of the DB view) is to map that joins as SecondaryTables.